# Musixtex chart for Professional Saxophone finger notation using Beamer with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, musixtex

It is needed to implement a Musixtex chart for Professional Saxophone finger notation using Beamer, When I try to use the code template from [Musixtex chart for professional saxophone finger notation using Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668021/musixtex-chart-for-professional-saxophone-finger-notation-using-tikz), for some reason the coordinates get wrong. The basic code is as follow:

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: xelatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{emerald}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float} %Paquete para posicionar Tablas
\usepackage{hyperref} %Referencias a las tablas
\usepackage{tabularx} %Tabla con ajuste de ancho
\usepackage{colortbl} %Color a tablas
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{gray-undar}{RGB}{52,52,52}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{\LARGE Partes de una Partitura}
    
\begin{table}[H]
    \caption{Registro grave}
    \label{tab:RegistroGrave}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rotate=0,transform shape,scale=0.7]{
    \centering\centering\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.1}
    \begin{tabular}{!{\color{red-undar}\vrule}m{1.6cm}!{\color{red-undar}\vrule}m{1.6cm}!{\color{red-undar}\vrule}m{1.6cm}!{\color{red-undar}\vrule}m{1.6cm}!{\color{red-undar}\vrule}m{1.6cm}!{\color{red-undar}\vrule}m{1.6cm}!{\color{red-undar}\vrule}m{1.6cm}!{\color{red-undar}\vrule}m{1.6cm}!{\color{red-undar}\vrule}m{1.6cm}!{\color{red-undar}\vrule}}
    \arrayrulecolor{red-undar}\hline  
    \begin{music}
        \parindent0mm
        \setclef1\treble % Clave de Sol para el Instrumento 1
        \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
        \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
        \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
        \notes \en
        \zendextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
    \end{music} & \begin{music}
        \parindent0mm
        \afterruleskip-7pt
        \setclefsymbol1\empty
        \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
        \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
        \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
        \scale{0.45}\notes \sh{a} \wh a \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.5cm} A\musSharp{}} 
        \sk\sk \fl{b} \wh b \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.55cm} B\musFlat{}}\en
        \zendextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
    \end{music} & \begin{music}
        \parindent0mm
        \afterruleskip-7pt
        \setclefsymbol1\empty
        \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
        \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
        \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
        \scale{0.45}\notes \wh b \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.41cm} B} 
        \sk\sk \fl{c} \wh c \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.55cm} C\musFlat{}}\en
        \zendextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
    \end{music}
        & \begin{music}
            \parindent0mm
            \afterruleskip-7pt
            \setclefsymbol1\empty
            \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
            \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
            \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
            \scale{0.45}\notes \wh c \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.4cm} C} 
            \sk\sk \sh{b} \wh b \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.55cm} B\musSharp{}}\en
            \zendextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
        \end{music} & \begin{music}
            \parindent0mm
            \afterruleskip-7pt
            \setclefsymbol1\empty
            \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
            \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
            \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
            \scale{0.45}\notes \sh{c} \wh c \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.5cm} C\musSharp{}} 
            \sk\sk \fl{d} \wh d \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.55cm} D\musFlat{}}\en
            \zendextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
        \end{music} & \begin{music}
            \parindent0mm
            %\afterruleskip-7pt
            \setclefsymbol1\empty
            \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
            \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
            \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
            %\scale{0.45}
            \NOtes \wh d \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-1.1cm} D}\en
            \zendextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
        \end{music} & \begin{music}
            \parindent0mm
            \afterruleskip-7pt
            \setclefsymbol1\empty
            \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
            \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
            \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
            \scale{0.45}\notes \sh{d} \wh d \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.54cm} D\musSharp{}} 
            \sk\sk \fl{e} \wh e \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.55cm} E\musFlat{}}\en
            \zendextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
        \end{music} & \begin{music}
            \parindent0mm
            \afterruleskip-7pt
            \setclefsymbol1\empty
            \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
            \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
            \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
            \scale{0.45}\notes \wh e \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.41cm} E} 
            \sk\sk \fl{f} \wh f \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.55cm} F\musFlat{}}\en
            \zendextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
        \end{music} & \begin{music}
            \parindent0mm
            \afterruleskip-7pt
            \setclefsymbol1\empty
            \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
            \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
            \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
            \scale{0.45}\notes \wh f \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.41cm} F} 
            \sk\sk \sh{e} \wh e \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.55cm} E\musSharp{}}\en
            \zendextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
        \end{music} \\ 
    \arrayrulecolor{red-undar}\hline
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3.8]
    %\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {
    %};
    \begin{scope}[x=3cm,y=1.3cm]
    %\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm]
        %Código para grillas
      %\draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
      %\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
      %\foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
    
      %Código para dibujar el Saxophone
      \draw [fill=blue] (0.67,1.0) ellipse (0.04cm and 0.09cm);
      \draw [fill=green] (0.685,0.95) ellipse (0.03cm and 0.13cm);
      \draw [fill=green] (0.69,0.90) ellipse (0.03cm and 0.13cm);
      \draw [fill=green] (0.68,0.85) ellipse (0.03cm and 0.13cm);
      \draw [fill=blue] (0.67,0.9) circle[radius=0.08cm];
      %\draw [fill=purple] (0.65,0.9) circle[radius=0.08cm];
      \draw[fill=purple] (0.65,0.9) ++(-0.05cm,0.1cm) to[bend left] ++(0.1cm,-0.25cm) to[bend right] ++(-0.1cm,0.05cm) to[bend right] cycle;
      \draw [fill=blue] (0.67,0.8) circle[radius=0.06cm];
      \draw [fill=gray] (0.67,0.7) circle[radius=0.08cm];
      \draw [fill=yellow] (0.67,0.6) circle[radius=0.08cm];
      \draw [fill=yellow] (0.69,0.6) ellipse (0.1cm and 0.03cm);
      \draw [fill=yellow,rounded corners=0.025cm] (0.683,0.54) rectangle (0.688,0.58);
      \draw [fill=yellow,rounded corners=0.025cm] (0.690,0.54) rectangle (0.695,0.58);
      \draw [fill=yellow] (0.69,0.52) ellipse (0.1cm and 0.03cm);
      \draw[] (0.635,0.6) -- ++(0.07,-0.2);
    
      \draw [fill=blue] (0.67,0.4) circle[radius=0.08cm];
      \draw [fill=gray] (0.67,0.3) circle[radius=0.08cm];
      \draw [fill=yellow] (0.67,0.2) circle[radius=0.08cm];
      \draw [fill=gray] (0.65,0.2) ellipse (0.1cm and 0.05cm);
      \draw [fill=green,rounded corners=0.025cm] (0.64,0.39) rectangle (0.645,0.44);
      \draw [fill=green,rounded corners=0.025cm] (0.64,0.32) rectangle (0.645,0.37);
      \draw [fill=green,rounded corners=0.025cm] (0.64,0.25) rectangle (0.645,0.3);
      \draw [fill=gray,rounded corners=0.025cm] (0.655,0.25) rectangle (0.66,0.35);
      \draw [fill=yellow,rounded corners=0.05cm] (0.64,0.15) rectangle (0.66,0.1);
      \draw [fill=yellow,rounded corners=0.05cm] (0.64,0.08) rectangle (0.66,0.03);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture} & & & & & & & & \\
    \arrayrulecolor{red-undar}\hline
    \end{tabular}
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{table}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

The desired output is as follow:
[image: desired]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adapt the scaling in the lines 123 and 126 until you get the result you want (and nesting tikzpictures is a really bad idea):

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: xelatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{emerald}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{float} %Paquete para posicionar Tablas
%\usepackage{hyperref} %Referencias a las tablas
\usepackage{tabularx} %Tabla con ajuste de ancho
%\usepackage{colortbl} %Color a tablas
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{gray-undar}{RGB}{52,52,52}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{\LARGE Partes de una Partitura}
\begin{table}%[H]
    \caption{Registro grave}
    \label{tab:RegistroGrave}
    \scalebox{0.7}{%
%    \begin{tikzpicture}
%    \node[rotate=0,transform shape,scale=0.7]{
    \centering\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.1}
    \begin{tabular}{!{\color{red-undar}\vrule}m{1.6cm}!{\color{red-undar}\vrule}m{1.6cm}!{\color{red-undar}\vrule}m{1.6cm}!{\color{red-undar}\vrule}m{1.6cm}!{\color{red-undar}\vrule}m{1.6cm}!{\color{red-undar}\vrule}m{1.6cm}!{\color{red-undar}\vrule}m{1.6cm}!{\color{red-undar}\vrule}m{1.6cm}!{\color{red-undar}\vrule}m{1.6cm}!{\color{red-undar}\vrule}}
    \arrayrulecolor{red-undar}\hline  
    \begin{music}
        \parindent0mm
        \setclef1\treble % Clave de Sol para el Instrumento 1
        \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
        \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
        \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
        \notes \en
        \zendextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
    \end{music} & \begin{music}
        \parindent0mm
        \afterruleskip-7pt
        \setclefsymbol1\empty
        \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
        \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
        \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
        \scale{0.45}\notes \sh{a} \wh a \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.5cm} A\musSharp{}} 
        \sk\sk \fl{b} \wh b \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.55cm} B\musFlat{}}\en
        \zendextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
    \end{music} & \begin{music}
        \parindent0mm
        \afterruleskip-7pt
        \setclefsymbol1\empty
        \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
        \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
        \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
        \scale{0.45}\notes \wh b \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.41cm} B} 
        \sk\sk \fl{c} \wh c \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.55cm} C\musFlat{}}\en
        \zendextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
    \end{music}
        & \begin{music}
            \parindent0mm
            \afterruleskip-7pt
            \setclefsymbol1\empty
            \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
            \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
            \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
            \scale{0.45}\notes \wh c \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.4cm} C} 
            \sk\sk \sh{b} \wh b \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.55cm} B\musSharp{}}\en
            \zendextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
        \end{music} & \begin{music}
            \parindent0mm
            \afterruleskip-7pt
            \setclefsymbol1\empty
            \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
            \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
            \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
            \scale{0.45}\notes \sh{c} \wh c \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.5cm} C\musSharp{}} 
            \sk\sk \fl{d} \wh d \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.55cm} D\musFlat{}}\en
            \zendextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
        \end{music} & \begin{music}
            \parindent0mm
            %\afterruleskip-7pt
            \setclefsymbol1\empty
            \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
            \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
            \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
            %\scale{0.45}
            \NOtes \wh d \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-1.1cm} D}\en
            \zendextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
        \end{music} & \begin{music}
            \parindent0mm
            \afterruleskip-7pt
            \setclefsymbol1\empty
            \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
            \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
            \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
            \scale{0.45}\notes \sh{d} \wh d \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.54cm} D\musSharp{}} 
            \sk\sk \fl{e} \wh e \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.55cm} E\musFlat{}}\en
            \zendextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
        \end{music} & \begin{music}
            \parindent0mm
            \afterruleskip-7pt
            \setclefsymbol1\empty
            \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
            \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
            \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
            \scale{0.45}\notes \wh e \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.41cm} E} 
            \sk\sk \fl{f} \wh f \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.55cm} F\musFlat{}}\en
            \zendextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
        \end{music} & \begin{music}
            \parindent0mm
            \afterruleskip-7pt
            \setclefsymbol1\empty
            \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
            \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
            \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
            \scale{0.45}\notes \wh f \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.41cm} F} 
            \sk\sk \sh{e} \wh e \zcharnote{10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-0.55cm} E\musSharp{}}\en
            \zendextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
        \end{music} \\ 
    \arrayrulecolor{red-undar}\hline
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    %\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {
    %};
    \begin{scope}[x=12cm,y=1.8cm]
    %\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm]
        %Código para grillas
      %\draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
      %\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
      %\foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
    
      %Código para dibujar el Saxophone
      \draw [fill=blue] (0.67,1.0) ellipse (0.04cm and 0.09cm);
      \draw [fill=green] (0.685,0.95) ellipse (0.03cm and 0.13cm);
      \draw [fill=green] (0.69,0.90) ellipse (0.03cm and 0.13cm);
      \draw [fill=green] (0.68,0.85) ellipse (0.03cm and 0.13cm);
      \draw [fill=blue] (0.67,0.9) circle[radius=0.08cm];
      %\draw [fill=purple] (0.65,0.9) circle[radius=0.08cm];
      \draw[fill=purple] (0.65,0.9) ++(-0.05cm,0.1cm) to[bend left] ++(0.1cm,-0.25cm) to[bend right] ++(-0.1cm,0.05cm) to[bend right] cycle;
      \draw [fill=blue] (0.67,0.8) circle[radius=0.06cm];
      \draw [fill=gray] (0.67,0.7) circle[radius=0.08cm];
      \draw [fill=yellow] (0.67,0.6) circle[radius=0.08cm];
      \draw [fill=yellow] (0.69,0.6) ellipse (0.1cm and 0.03cm);
      \draw [fill=yellow,rounded corners=0.025cm] (0.683,0.54) rectangle (0.688,0.58);
      \draw [fill=yellow,rounded corners=0.025cm] (0.690,0.54) rectangle (0.695,0.58);
      \draw [fill=yellow] (0.69,0.52) ellipse (0.1cm and 0.03cm);
      \draw[] (0.635,0.6) -- ++(0.07,-0.2);
    
      \draw [fill=blue] (0.67,0.4) circle[radius=0.08cm];
      \draw [fill=gray] (0.67,0.3) circle[radius=0.08cm];
      \draw [fill=yellow] (0.67,0.2) circle[radius=0.08cm];
      \draw [fill=gray] (0.65,0.2) ellipse (0.1cm and 0.05cm);
      \draw [fill=green,rounded corners=0.025cm] (0.64,0.39) rectangle (0.645,0.44);
      \draw [fill=green,rounded corners=0.025cm] (0.64,0.32) rectangle (0.645,0.37);
      \draw [fill=green,rounded corners=0.025cm] (0.64,0.25) rectangle (0.645,0.3);
      \draw [fill=gray,rounded corners=0.025cm] (0.655,0.25) rectangle (0.66,0.35);
      \draw [fill=yellow,rounded corners=0.05cm] (0.64,0.15) rectangle (0.66,0.1);
      \draw [fill=yellow,rounded corners=0.05cm] (0.64,0.08) rectangle (0.66,0.03);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture} & & & & & & & & \\
    \arrayrulecolor{red-undar}\hline
    \end{tabular}
%    };
%    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{table}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]